# Debugging a system preference pane on Xcode 14, "Breakpoint has not been resolved." Why?

Tags: xcode, macos, debugging, breakpoints

I can build and run my prefpane, but I find that I can't use any breakpoints. Whenever I run, they become disabled and hovering over them gives me

```
Xcode won't pause at this breakpoint because it has not been resolved.
Resolving it requires that:
• The line at the breakpoint is compiled.
• The compiler generates debug information
that is not stripped out (check the Build
Settings).
• The library for the breakpoint is loaded.
```

Why is this happening?

I have checked that it is in fact compiled, that the code IS being run, that debug symbols ARE being generated, that the product is not stripped, that the files have their correct membership. that hardened runtime isn't turned on and also, SIP is off. So... what am I missing?

This is happening on a workspace. I tried deleting all breakpoints and creating them at the project level, also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much searching and trying different proposed solutions, I finally realized that the root of the issue in my case is the fact I'm running a PreferencePane, rather than anything else.

It's not possible to attach the debugger normally to `System Preferences.app` because then symbols can't be resolved. Instead, the proper way to do it is attaching to the legacy loader located inside the `PreferencePanes.framework`

Source: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/69431#649239022